# d3.js horizontal bar graph with positive and negative values - move y axis labels to far left side of graph

Tags: d3.js

On a horizontal bar graph with positive and negative values, where the y axis would sit somewhere mid page, how would we move the y axis labels to the far left side. Taking this jsfiddle as an example, can we move foo, bar, etc. away from the y axis to the far left side of the graph?
https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/fmr1x1gu/18/

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
width = 500,
height = 300;

var data = [{value: -10, dataset:"barbaz"},
{value: 40, dataset:"barbar"},
{value: -10, dataset:"foobaz"},
{value: -50, dataset:"foobar"},
{value: 30, dataset:"baz"},
{value: -20, dataset:"bar"},
{value: -70, dataset:"foo"}];

// Add svg to
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width +  

margin.left   + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + 

margin.bottom).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left 

+ ',' + margin.top + ')');
```

// set the ranges

```
var y = d3.scaleBand()
.range([height, 0])
.padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, width]);

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.dataset;
}));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.dataset);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by moving the ticks manually:

```
// add the y Axis
let yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisRight(y));
yAxisGroup.selectAll('.tick')
  .data(data)
  .select('text')
  .attr('x', function(d,i){return d.value<0?9:-9})
  .style('text-anchor', function(d,i){return d.value<0?'start':'end'})
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmr1x1gu/19/)